# mysql table fields - Resource id #6

Tags: php

I have a database (db_name=members) with a lot of fields but the relevant ones for this are:

```
security_question, security_answer, email
```

The php code is:

```
$email = $_COOKIE['site_user'];

$select_sa = mysql_query("SELECT security_answer FROM members WHERE email='".$email."'");
$result_sa = mysql_query($select_sa);
$arr_sa = mysql_fetch_row($result_sa);
$result2 = $arr_sa[0];
$get_sa = $result2;
```

If I

```
  echo $select_sa;
```

It prints "Resource id #6" although in the table I can see the security answer as a word and not "Resource id #6".

If I

```
echo $get_sa;
```

It prints nothing.

---

Could you please help me to be able to read the securty_answer field from the database ?

Thanks,
Ray

Answer (score 3):

You're doing the query twice, feeding the result handle from the first time into the query text parameter of the second one. That's invalid. Try this instead:

```
$select_sa = "SELECT security_answer FROM members WHERE email='".$email."'";
$result_sa = mysql_query($select_sa);
$arr_sa = mysql_fetch_row($result_sa);
$result2 = $arr_sa[0];
$get_sa = $result2;
```

Please also make sure that the `$email` field is being passed through `mysql_real_escape_string()` before being used in the query. All data fetched from the user, e.g. via `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_COOKIE`, **must** be escaped properly. If you don't escape it, you'll be open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thank you so much. Problem sorted now and yes I am planning to spend some more time on security. Cheers :)

Comment: Glad it helped. If you're looking to read up on security w.r.t SQL injection, check out parameterized queries and stored procedures. They're both great tools to ensure that your queries remain safe.